# Rain effect in webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, effect

I am trying to make a rain effect to to my website, but i cant (I have tried a loooooot of js code, but no one seems to work... but in the demo pages they work perfectly... the last one i'm trying is in this page:

http://redeando.blogspot.com/2013/02/lluvia-en-tu-blog.html

and the code:

```
<div class="lluvia"></div><style>
.gotas {
background:-webkit-gradient(linear,0% 0%,0% 100%, from(rgba(13,52,58,1) ),          to(rgba(255,255,255,0.6))  );
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(13,52,58,1) 0%,      rgba(255,255,255,.6) 100%);
width:1px;height:89px;
position: absolute;top:0px;z-index:99999;
-webkit-animation: fall .63s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation: fall .63s linear infinite;
 }
@-webkit-keyframes fall {
to {margin-top:900px;}
}
@-moz-keyframes fall {
 to {margin-top:900px;}
}
 </style><script type="text/javascript">

 (function() {

 var nbDrop = 200; 

 function randRange( minNum, maxNum) {
  return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNum - minNum + 1)) + minNum);
 }

 function createRain() {

  for( i=1;i<nbDrop;i++) {
  var dropLeft = randRange(0,980);
 var dropTop = randRange(-1000,1400);

  $('.lluvia').append('<div class="gotas" id="gotas'+i+'"></div>');
  $('#gotas'+i).css('left',dropLeft);
  $('#gotas'+i).css('top',dropTop);
  }

 }

 createRain();

 })();

 </script>
```

can anyone help me to achieve the rain effect?? helping me with this code, or if you know other way??

the problem is: when i put the code it seems to be glitched or something... see the image...!

[image]

all the drops are condensed or squished at the bottom of the page...

Comment: The code you've shown "works" in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F8b5Z/) (in Chrome, anyway). If the effect is simply not to your taste could you perhaps be a bit clearer about what you want?

Comment: Tss tss... You should not visit the SkidRow guys. They are EVIL :D. This code does not seem very robust. It won't run on IE11, for instance. Since everything is in Spanish, I'll pass on this one.

Comment: Have you inspected your page on web developer kit ???

Comment: @nnnnnn The rain drops are falling the right way, but they're upside down! I'm freaking out, man!

Comment: @Birrel they're not upside-down on  a black background :D :D

Comment: What a terrible effect...

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027153/can-i-create-rain-effect-in-javascript?rq=1

Comment: @ameer: why did you try and change the link to `http://google.com`?

Comment: I was testing the formatting to see why it wasn't working, didn't see the link change at the bottom. It wasn't working because of the indent.

Comment: thanks to all of you guys, the effect is already working :D but someone knows a better way?

Comment: yep guys, i made it.. it were just a "bad div position"... lol if you wanna check out, go ahead --> http://deadly.sytes.net/info.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>

<h1>Content</h1>

<p>Hello!!!</p>
</html>






<style>
body, html {
  margin: 0px; 
  padding: 0px; 
}

canvas {
  z-index: 999; 
  margin: 0px; 
  padding: 0px; 
  background-color: transparent; 
  position: absolute; 
}

h1, p {
  text-align: center; 
}
</style>






<script>
var rainNum = 100;

var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var w = window.innerWidth / 1.1; var h = window.innerHeight / 1.1;
var x = 100; var y = 100;

var rain = [];
for(i = 0; i < rainNum; i++) {
  rain.push(new newRain);
}

function newRain() {
  this.x = Math.random() * w;
  this.y = Math.random() * h;
}

var draw = function() {
  c.width = w;
  c.height = h;

  for(t = 0; t < rain.length; t++) {
    var r = rain[t];

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.fillRect(r.x, r.y, 2, 20);

    r.y++;

    if(r.y > h + 20) {
      r.y = -20;
    }
  }
};

setInterval(draw, 3);
</script>
```